# jquery mobile 1.3 beta side panel scrollable content

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can I make the side panel content scrollable in case there are many items, without scrolling the content on the main page (in JQM 1.3 Beta)? I am trying to implement this for an application running on both Desktop and Mobile browsers.Have looked everywhere, but cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a div inside the panel that is scrollable, but this doesn't work on iOS4 and below without 2-finger scrolling (div within div issue in iOS).

Comment: Did not work for me? Does your look something like this (forgive me for bad formatting; cannot tag it as a code snippet): sidebar {
   position:fixed;
   left:0;
   top:0;
   overflow:scroll;
  } <div data-role="panel" id="myPanel" class="ui-response sidebar" data-position="left"> <div> <p> content content content</div> </div>

Answer (score 0):

Please, visit the following to find the answer to the above question:

JQM 1.3 panel + iscrollview + dynamically loaded 
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jqm-1-3-panel-iscrollview-dynamically-loaded-pages

jquery-mobile-iscrollview 
https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview

Answer (score 0):

```
.ui-panel-inner .ui-content myElement {
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

You can make the selector more specific to a given element or just leave the "ui-panel-inner" if you want the whole side panel to be scrollable.

Note: The "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch" adds native inertia scrolling to the overflow and is not needed if all you want is scroll functionality. This should work on webkit browsers; mobile safari and chrome. But I have only tested it on mobile safari. It will not work on mobile IE but again, I have not tested it.